# Scroll to section in HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

if I have the following JS code:

```
 //Scroll Down button
    $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollDown() > 100) {
      $('.containerScroll').fadeIn('slow');
    } else {
      $('.containerScroll').fadeOut('slow');
    }
  });

  $('.containerScroll').click(function () {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
    return false;
  });
```

This basically is for the Back-top-button animation where if the user clicks the button, then it brings the user back to the homepage with smooth scrolling. I would like the opposite. Is there a way to modify the above JS code so that when the user clicks the button, it brings the user to whichever page they desire? Right now, this scrolls all the way to the top and brings the user to only the homepage of the website, but how can I make it so it would bring the user to whichever page on the website?

This is what I have in HTML file:

```
<a href="#about" class="containerScroll">
      <div class="first-scroll"></div>
      <div class="second-scroll"></div>
      </a>
```

Basically, I would like the user to go in the about section of the page instead of the homepage. Any suggestions on how to achieve this task?

Answer (score 3):

You can set the scrollTop value to the offset of whatever element you want. For example:

```
$('html, body').scrollTop($('#about').offset().top);
```

will set scrollTop to the top of the element with id `about` by getting its offset.

Or you could use animate as you did in your example:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    'scrollTop': $('#about').offset().top
}, 1500);
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6bLh5xd1/)

[Fiddle smooth scroll](https://jsfiddle.net/p8ef4ymz/1/)

Comment: Can you share the whole working code, like add some parts to it that are missing...etc?

Comment: Added JSFiddle.

Comment: hmm its not smooth scroll though

Comment: Use the second example for smooth scrolling.

Comment: Instead of `'scrollTop'` I add my own class right?

Comment: No, scrollTop is the distance scrolled. We're setting the value of scrollTop to the top of the element with ID 'about' (i.e., scroll to the top of that element). So in your case you'd have a div for each section of the website, each with an ID. You'd then set the scrollTop value to the offset of each div.

Comment: can you take a look at the HTML code in my post? How would I modify it? Because I feel like I'm doing something wrong which is why it is not working on my end

Answer (score 3):

to top

```js
window.scrollTo({
  top: 0,
  behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

to element

```js
const element = getElementById("someElement");
//you can do it by jquery. no matter
element.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "end", inline: "nearest"});
```

MDM: [scrolIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

MDM: [scrollTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo)

Comment: I want to scroll to About page, so do I add an ID in replacement of `"someElement"` and then add that into HTML right?

Comment: yes. you can ad some id to about section of page and then scroll to it.